# Split strings on string array

Tags: android, string

i have String Array like this:

```
String[] q1={"AAA-BBB","AAA-CCC","AAA-DDD"}
```

and i want result like this

```
temp={"BBB","CCC","DDD"}
```

i tried below code but the result is wrong

```
 for(int i=0;i<q1.length;i++){
       ArrayList<String> temp=new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(q1[i].split("AAA-")));

    }
```

Comment: In your split("AAA-") method instead of AAA- use only "-".  Also initialize your temp outside the for loop, only add the values inside the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

```
  ArrayList<String> temp=new ArrayList<>();
   for(int i=0;i<q1.length;i++){
        String[] array = q1[i].split("-");
        temp.add(array[1]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use substring:

```
ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();    

for(int i=0; i<q1.length; i++){
   temp.add(q[i].substring(q[i].indexOf('-') + 1, q[i].length()))

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried creating the ArrayList outside of the loop?  As previously you were creating a new ArrayList for every element in your string array

```
ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0;i<q1.length;i++){
   temp.add(q1[i].substring(4);
}
```

Assuming that "AAA-" is not going to change.

Answer (score 1):

you find error Because you use split

> Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.
>   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

```
q1[i].split("AAA-")
```

in this line you got 2 result splited 0 = "" AND 1 = "BBB" 
so you need to pick the sec result

**you have multi Solution**

like https://stackoverflow.com/a/50234408/6998825 said

```
    String[] array = q1[i].split("-");
    temp.add(array[1]);
```

---

```
//change this q1[i].split("AAA-") to
q1[0].substring(4)
```

if your AAA- is not going to change